# How do you loop over the indexes of a string?

Tags: string, loops, indexing, ats

Consider:

```
val example = "1234567"

fn digit(c: char): int =
  case- c of
  | '0' => 0 | '1' => 1 | '2' => 2 | '3' => 3 | '4' => 4
  | '5' => 5 | '6' => 6 | '7' => 7 | '8' => 8 | '9' => 9

fn f(): int = loop(0, 0) where {
  fun loop(i: int, acc: int): int =
    if example[i] = '\000' then acc else
    loop(i + 1, acc + digit(example[i]))
}

implement main0() = () where {
  val () = println!("f: ", f())
}
```

This (tries to) loop over the indices of a string, summing the characters of the string as digits. I've solved several similar problems with `.foldleft` and with `streamize_string_char`, but the actual task requires *math on the indexes themselves* (i.e., instead of using every char, it should only use a char if the char at i+10 is as an even-numbered digit).

Actually the math is relevant, because it seems to force `$UNSAFE.cast2int`, since there's no division operator for the result of `strlen(input)`:

```
fn day2(): uint = loop(input, 0, 0) where {
  val len = $UNSAFE.cast2int(strlen(input))
  fn nextindex(i: int): int = (i + len/2) mod len
  fn get(i: int): char = input[i]  // <-- also broken at this point
  // this next line is just me slowly going mad
  fun loop{n:int}{i:nat | i <= n}(s: string(n), i: size_t(i), acc: uint): uint =
    if i >= len then acc else
    if s[i] = s[nextindex(i)] then loop(i+1, acc + digit(s[i])) else
    loop(i+1, acc)
}
```

How should `f()` be written above? Please give me an example of a function that loops over the indexes of a string and fetches chars by index from the string. Again I don't need a solution like

```
typedef charint = (char, int)
fn day1(): int = sum where {
  val lastchar = input[strlen(input)-1]
  val res = input.foldleft(TYPE{charint})((lastchar, 0), (lam((last, sum): charint, c: char) =>
                if last = c then (c, sum + digit(c)) else (c, sum)))
  val sum = res.1
}
```

because I need to test properties based on the indices.

EDIT:

Well I finally came up with *some* kind of solution, but look at how absurd it is. There must be a right and proper ATS way to do this.

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

val example = "1234567"

fn digit(c: char): int =
  case- c of
  | '0' => 0 | '1' => 1 | '2' => 2 | '3' => 3 | '4' => 4
  | '5' => 5 | '6' => 6 | '7' => 7 | '8' => 8 | '9' => 9

fn f(): int = loop(0, 0) where {
  fn get(i: int): char = loop(i, string2ptr(example)) where {
    fun loop(i: int, s: ptr): char =
      if i > 0 then loop(i-1, ptr0_succ<char>(s)) else
      $UNSAFE.ptr0_get<char>(s)
  }
  fun loop(i: int, acc: int): int =
    if get(i) = '\000' then acc else
    loop(i + 1, acc + digit(get(i)))
}

implement main0() = () where {
  val () = println!("f: ", f())
}
```

Outputs:

```
f: 28
```

EDIT2:

less absurd:

```
...
  val p = string2ptr(example)
  fn get(i: int): char = $UNSAFE.ptr0_get<char>(add_ptr_bsz(p, g0int2uint(i) * sizeof<char>))
...
```

EDIT3:

I can use `string[i]` again with

```
overload + with add_ptr_bsz
fn string_get_at(str, i) = $UNSAFE.ptr0_get<charNZ>(string2ptr(str)+g0int2uint(i))
overload [] with string_get_at
```

which is almost identical to what I see in prelude/DATS/string.dats ... what's the problem?

Comment: approved edits, but I doubt that there's going to be any benefit from increased visibility. If you don't know ATS you just can't answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the following implementation of `day2` is safe:

```
fn
day2
(input: string): uint = let

val
[n:int]
input = g1ofg0(input)

val n0 = strlen(input)
val n0 = sz2i(n0) // int(n)

fun
nextindex
(
 i: natLt(n)
) : natLt(n) = nmod(i + n0/2, n0)

fun
loop(i: natLte(n), acc: uint): uint =
  if i >= n0 then acc else
  (
    if input[i] = input[nextindex(i)]
      then loop(i+1, acc + digit2uint(input[i]))
      else loop(i+1, acc)
  )

in
  loop(0, 0u)
end // end of [day2]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions here. Your function `f()` can be written as:

```
fn digit2int(c: char): int = (c - '0')
fn f(): int = loop(example, 0, 0) where
{
  fun
  loop
  {n:int}
  {i:nat|i <= n}
  (cs: string(n), i: int(i), acc: int): int =
  if
  string_is_atend(cs, i)
  then acc else loop(cs, i+1, acc+digit2int(cs[i]))
}
```

This kind of programming involves dependent types. It often demands much more from the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I gave a try to re-implement your function `day2`:

```
fn digit2int(c: char): int = (c - '0')

fn
day2(input: string): int =
  loop(0, 0) where
{
  val n0 = strlen(input)
  val n0 =
  g0uint2int_size_int(n0)
  val p0 = string2ptr(input)
  fn nextindex(i: int): int = (i + n0/2) mod n0
  fun get(i: int): char = $UNSAFE.ptr0_get_at<char>(p0, i)
  fun loop(i: int, acc: int): int =
    if i >= n0 then acc else
    (
      if get(i) = get(nextindex(i))
        then loop(i+1, acc + digit2int(get(i))) else loop(i+1, acc)
    )
}
```

I have to say that the above implementation is very ugly (and of very unsafe style). If I have time, I will try to give a safe and elegant implementation later.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to finish the job with the help provided, but just so that there is also a complete functional example, here is a solution to [Day 1, 2017 Advent of Code](http://adventofcode.com/2017/day/1):

```
/* compile with: patscc -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC day1.dats -o day1 */
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"
#include "share/atspre_staload_libats_ML.hats"

val input: string = "12341234" /* actual value provided by contest */

fn digit(c: char): uint =
  case- c of
  | '0' => 0u | '1' => 1u | '2' => 2u | '3' => 3u | '4' => 4u
  | '5' => 5u | '6' => 6u | '7' => 7u | '8' => 8u | '9' => 9u

typedef charint = (char, uint)

fn part1(): uint = sum where {
  val lastchar = input[strlen(input)-1]
  val res = input.foldleft(TYPE{charint})((lastchar, 0u), (lam((last, sum): charint, c: char) =>
                if last = c then (c, sum + digit(c)) else (c, sum)))
  val sum = res.1
}

typedef natLT(n:int) = [i:nat | i < n] int(i)
typedef natLTe(n:int) = [i:nat | i <= n] int(i)

fn part2(): uint = loop(0, 0u) where {
  val [n:int] input = g1ofg0(input)
  val len = sz2i(strlen(input))
  fn nextindex(i: natLT(n)): natLT(n) = nmod(i + len/2, len)
  fun loop(i: natLTe(n), acc: uint): uint =
    if i >= len then acc else
    if input[i] = input[nextindex(i)] then loop(i+1, acc + digit(input[i])) else
    loop(i+1, acc)
}

extern fun reset_timer(): void = "ext#reset_timer"
extern fun elapsed_time(): double = "ext#elapsed_time"
%{
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
struct timeval timer_timeval;
void reset_timer() { gettimeofday(&timer_timeval, NULL); }
double elapsed_time() {
  struct timeval now;
  gettimeofday(&now, NULL);
  int secs = now.tv_sec - timer_timeval.tv_sec;
  double ms = (now.tv_usec - timer_timeval.tv_usec) / ((double)1000000);
  return(secs + ms);
}
%}

fn bench(f: () -> void) = () where {
  val () = reset_timer()
  val () = f()
  val c = elapsed_time()
  val () = println!(" (timing: ", c, ")")
}

implement main0() =
  begin
    bench(lam() => print!("part1: ", part1()));
    bench(lam() => print!("part2: ", part2()));
  end
```

Output (for the fake "12341234" input):

```
part1: 0 (timing: 0.000137)
part2: 20 (timing: 0.000001)
```