# How to index a string in ATS?

Tags: ats

Say I have a string xyz and I want to find the char in xyz that is of index 4.
For instance, in the case where xyz = `("Hello": string)`, then the char should be 'o'. I tried the syntax xyz[4] but it did not work.

Comment: I was actually having problem with `fun foo(xyz: string): char = xyz[4]`

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of a question that requires an attempt at code, because as written the answer is "what you say doesn't work, actually works just fine." Consider this complete program:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

implement main0() =
  let
    val s: string = "Hello"
    val c1: char = s[4]
    val c2: char = string_get_at("Hello",4)
    (* val c3: char = "Hello"[4]   // syntax error *)
  in
    println!("\"", s, "\"[4] = ", c1);
    println!("\"", s, "\"[4] = ", c2);
  end
```

Which compiles and runs with this output:

```
$ make stringindex
patscc -O2 -flto -D_GNU_SOURCE -DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC stringindex.dats -o stringindex -latslib
$ ./stringindex
"Hello"[4] = o
"Hello"[4] = o
```

You can find the `xyz[4]` syntax at the definition of `c1`. On the next line is an example of the same with a literal string, using one of the functions that `[]` is overloaded to. `"Hello"[4]` is syntax that seems like it should work, but ATS fails to parse it.

Note that the type annotations aren't needed in the code above, mainly because the code is correct. If it were *incorrect*, the type annotations could show their use by guiding the compiler towards emitting a (useful) "you gave me [this type] but I wanted [that type]" error instead of a (frustrating) "you used [overloaded symbol] and I couldn't find anything matching the types involved".

The latter error you can see with this code:

```
#include "share/atspre_staload.hats"

implement main0() =
  let
    val s = "Hello"
    val i = '\x04'
    val c = s[i]
  in
    println!("\"", s, "\"[4] = ", c);
  end
```

Which fails to compile:

```
$ make stringindex2
patscc -O2 -flto -D_GNU_SOURCE -DATS_MEMALLOC_LIBC stringindex2.dats -o stringindex2 -latslib
/home/jfondren/ats/learn/stringindex2.dats: 116(line=7, offs=13) -- 120(line=7, offs=17): error(3): the symbol [[]] cannot be resolved as no match is found.
/home/jfondren/ats/learn/stringindex2.dats: 130(line=9, offs=5) -- 162(line=9, offs=37): error(3): the symbol [print] cannot be resolved due to too many matches:
D2ITMcst(print_option) of 0
D2ITMcst(print_list_vt) of 0
/home/jfondren/ats/learn/stringindex2.dats: 130(line=9, offs=5) -- 162(line=9, offs=37): error(3): the dynamic expression cannot be assigned the type [S2Ecst(atsvoid_t0ype)].
/home/jfondren/ats/learn/stringindex2.dats: 130(line=9, offs=5) -- 162(line=9, offs=37): error(3): mismatch of static terms (tyleq):
The actual term is: S2Eerrexp()
The needed term is: S2Ecst(atsvoid_t0ype)
patsopt(TRANS3): there are [3] errors in total.
exit(ATS): uncaught exception: _2home_2hwxi_2Research_2ATS_2dPostiats_2src_2pats_error_2esats__FatalErrorExn(1025)
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'stringindex2' failed
make: *** [stringindex2] Error 1
```

If you're trying to do some string processing in ATS, I think you won't have trouble looking up a constant index from a constant string, but you may well see a lot of `the symbol [[]] cannot be resolved`. Try starting with the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48144507/how-do-you-loop-over-the-indexes-of-a-string) about looping over a string by its indexes.